# Problem setting up linker options for different configs using generator expressions

Tags: cmake

CMake 3.23

I'm trying to generate different C++ linker options for debug vs release.
First, I setup some variables with the flags. The idea is that some flags
pertain to all configs, and some only to debug or release.

It works with `target_compile_options`, but not for `set_target_properties`.

```
# Win32 all configs:
set(win32DynLinkerFlagsAllConfigs
    /MAP /FORCE
)
# Win32 Debug only:
set(win32DynLinkerFlagsDebug
    /DEBUG:FASTLINK
)
# Win32 Release only:
set(win32DynLinkerFlagsRelease
    /FOOBAR
)
```

The following gives an error:

`CMake Error at CMake/CommonTarget.cmake:82 (set_target_properties): set_target_properties called with incorrect number of arguments.`

```
set_target_properties(common_target PROPERTIES
    INTERFACE_LINK_OPTIONS
        "$<${isWindows}:${win32DynLinkerFlagsAllConfigs}>"
        "$<${isWindows}:$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:${win32DynLinkerFlagsDebug}>>"
        "$<${isWindows}:$<$<CONFIG:Release>:${win32DynLinkerFlagsRelease}>>"
)
```

The following doesn't give error, but only uses the last one.

```
set_target_properties(common_target PROPERTIES
    INTERFACE_LINK_OPTIONS
        "$<${isWindows}:${win32DynLinkerFlagsAllConfigs}>"
    INTERFACE_LINK_OPTIONS
        "$<${isWindows}:$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:${win32DynLinkerFlagsDebug}>>"
    INTERFACE_LINK_OPTIONS    
        "$<${isWindows}:$<$<CONFIG:Release>:${win32DynLinkerFlagsRelease}>>"
)
```

However, a similar thing DOES work for compiler options:

```
target_compile_options(common_target
    INTERFACE
        "$<${g_isWindows}:${win32CompilerOptionsAllConfigs}>"
        "$<${g_isWindows}:$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:${win32CompilerOptionsDebug}>>"
        "$<${g_isWindows}:$<$<CONFIG:Release>:${win32CompilerOptionsRelease}>>"
)
```

How can one accomplish the same thing being done for `target_compile_options` above, but for `set_target_properties`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`set_target_properties` expects **one** argument after each property.

```
set_target_properties(common_target PROPERTIES
    INTERFACE_LINK_OPTIONS
        "$<${isWindows}:${win32DynLinkerFlagsAllConfigs}>"
        "$<${isWindows}:$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:${win32DynLinkerFlagsDebug}>>"
        "$<${isWindows}:$<$<CONFIG:Release>:${win32DynLinkerFlagsRelease}>>"
)
```

Here, though, you have supplied three and since `"$<${isWindows}:$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:${win32DynLinkerFlagsDebug}>>"` is not a property name, you get an error.

Write this instead:

```
set(link_options
    "$<${isWindows}:${win32DynLinkerFlagsAllConfigs}>"
    "$<${isWindows}:$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:${win32DynLinkerFlagsDebug}>>"
    "$<${isWindows}:$<$<CONFIG:Release>:${win32DynLinkerFlagsRelease}>>"
)
set_target_properties(common_target PROPERTIES "${link_options}")
```